# Document multi-label classification - where do you get the labels? Ontology?

Tags: ontology, n-gram, document-classification, vowpalwabbit

I am familiar with data mining techniques but not so much with text mining or Web mining.

Here is a simple task: classify articles into a set of categories.
Let us assume, I extracted text content of the article and processed it.

How and where do you get the categories - pre-defined labels? Is it possible to plug-in an ontology, taxonomy for that and go as granular as needed? Classification task will be a multi-label classification.

Do we use n-grams in this case for approximate matching?

Currently I have themes and named entities extracted from the text. 
Can I use Vowpal Wabbit for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How and where do you get the categories - pre-defined labels?

There are many benchmark text datasets with taxonomy and ontology information. [Wordnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet) is one such a popular benchmark dataset used in text analysis research. [This](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/P/P94/P94-1019.pdf) is the first paper that focused on using taxonomy to arrive at a semantic similarity for text analysis on Wordnet. . [This](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.5444.pdf?origin=publication_detail) is a more recent good paper dealing with similar objective.

> Is it possible to plug-in an ontology, taxonomy for that and go as granular as needed?

Yes. There is a research subfield that deals with arriving at a semantic similarity based on taxonomy and ontology that exist among the concepts (in this case, concepts in text documents). This [paper](http://dspace.library.drexel.edu/bitstream/1860/2754/1/2006175421.pdf) provides an overview and comparative study of techniques that bring in ontology and taxonomy into measuring similarities among documents. //go as granular as needed// - Yes, you can do so, by arriving at a new similarity measure that controls the granularity. Many research work pertain to this. This [paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/224041454_Ontology-based_semantic_similarity_A_new_feature-based_approach/file/e0b495149d58680c80.pdf) is a recent example.

> Do we use n-grams in this case for approximate matching?

Yes possible, but the aforementioned papers use less granular approaches that model concepts from documents. Most of them use tf-idf and not n-grams of terms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is very helpful to begin with NLP.

Comment: @Annamalai N Can you please check the links to the papers you've mentioned and possibly update them?